# returning a const char* from a function

Tags: c++, stdstring

I have to replace some char array code.  So say I have a class that has an std::string member variable.

```
class foo
{
private:
  std::string _sBar;

public:
  const char* getBar() const { return _sBar.c_str(); }
};
```

existing code expects that `const char*`'s are returned in the string accessor functions, so I can't return a `const std::string` reference.

But isn't there some rule that when the stack unwinds that you can no longer trust the return value from the `_sBar.c_str()` ?

Comment: This is bad. You are returning a pointer to free'd memory. Edit: Modifying the string or releasing the class will yield in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore. I would not suggest doing this, this passes the requirement of memory management along the call chain, which is bad. Think of exceptions here.

Comment: @Samuel - can you elaborate on when exactly the memory is free'd?

Comment: Sorry. I hit enter too early. As you mentioned, when the class goes out of scope then the address of c string is marked as free. Furthermore I am unsure whether the pointer remains valid if string needs to expand itself during insertion of additional chars.

Comment: std::string has an internal buffer, it was my understanding that c_str() returns a pointer to that internal buffer.  But I recall reading (ages ago) that returning the result of c_str() was bad.  I'm looking specifically for the reason why it's bad...

Comment: see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str: The pointer obtained from c_str() may be invalidated by:
Passing a non-const reference to the string to any standard library function, or
Calling non-const member functions on the string, excluding operator[], at(), front(), back(), begin(), rbegin(), end() and rend().

Comment: thanks SirDarius, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's correct. Better if you ask the caller to supply a buffer with a fixed size say, the caller allocates as:

```
const int MAX = 1000; // choose some suitable value
char buff[MAX];
```

And the caller has a foo object,

```
foo a;

...

a.getBar(buff, MAX);

...
```

And you define getBar as:

```
 void getBar(char *buffer, int size) const { 
   strncpy(buffer, _sBar.c_str(), size -1);
   buffer[size -1] = 0;
 }
```

Comment: I can't change the prototype of the accessor function - a large body of existing code expects that const char*'s are returned in the string accessor functions.  Guess std::string's aren't the best option in this case.

Comment: +1 although I'd recommend adding a `length` method to the `foo` class that returns the string's length so the caller knows by advance how many characters to allocate.

Comment: sorry, I agree that your implementation would solve the problem, but it doesn't answer my question - my requirements are specific - I can't change the prototype of the accessor function

Answer (score 0):

you can make a copy of that string with new [ ] operator inside your member function, and it will be stored independently from the class object. In the class:

```
plublic:
const char* getBar() const {
char * str = new char[_sBar.length()+1];
strcpy(str, _sBar.c_str());
return str;}
```

In main:

```
foo object;
///some code
const char* bar = object.getBar();
///some code
delete [] bar;
```

Note it's good style to free the memory using delete [ ].